# How to check the user who opened the record in salesforce is the owner of the record or not?

Tags: formula

I am new to sales force. I'd be glad if you could clarify my question. question may be silly, but I am in learning phase, so please bear with me :)

1. User is login into a sales force organization
2. He is opening a record, so we have to find out that is the user who opened the record (let's say Account record) is the record owner or not?

What I found is we have to write if-else block:

```
If($userinfo.getUserId == recordId.Ownerid){
    ...
}else{
    ... 
}
```

other solutions would be helpful for me.

Comment: When you say opened, do you mean edit?

Comment: That method works well. Is that not meeting your needs?

Comment: I agree with @mikeChale.  What you have seems fine.  Should work.  Do you have other requirements you're not mentioning?

Comment: If($userinfo.getUserId == recordId.Ownerid) will work fine if we know which record we are viewing, but here we don't know which object record we are going into, it might be standard or custom object.

Comment: Well what's your use case.  What are you trying to accomplish on the page.  You should be able to know what record you are using because it would be a property within your controller

Comment: All sObjects have the field OwnerId so even if you use dynamic Apex you can run this check.

Comment: Thank you @SF_Ninja and Mike Chale for your information.
I will try to create dynamic Apex for custom object.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you're using it you don't need code to do this. Create a formula field on the record that does the same thing.

Comment: Which is also very useful for filtering in List Views and other places.

Comment: e.g. checkbox formula field: `Is_Running_User_The_Owner__c`